# multiply sample space coin flipping

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

I have a question:
An experiment: a coin is flipped.
if we have HEAD than we flip a tetrahedron $(t_1 \ldots t_4)$.
if we have Number than we flip a cube $(c_1 \ldots c_6)$.

1.Now i am to find Ω.And here am not sure.

Ω={t1..t4,if **H**}U{c1..c6 ,if **N**}=10.

2.And for example ,probability to get odd number of cube flipping is
3/10 or 6/10 or 1/4?

thank you!

Comment: Do you mean "If we have Tails then we flip a cube" (instead of "number") ?

Comment: If you are asking how large the sample space is, yes, the size of the sample space is $10$.  How you choose to write that is largely personal preference.  I would have written it as $\{(c_h,T_1),(c_h,T_2),(c_h,T_3),(c_h,T_4),(c_t,C_1),(c_t,C_2),\dots\}$ with $(c_h,T_3)$ meaning that we flipped a **h**ead on the **c**oin and we rolled a $3$ on the Tetrahedral die.

Comment: Now... as for finding the probability that at the end of the experiment we ended by rolling an odd number on the cube, *NO!* this is *not* simply dividing the total number of good cases divided by the total number of outcomes in the sample space.  You may *only* do that if each outcome in the sample space is equally likely to occur.  That is not the case here.  The six outcomes which correspond to rolling a cube only occur when we flipped a tail which happens only half of the time.

Comment: and to find probability will be 1/2 (number-head) * probability of odd number 2/6?i see i should go like with tree-diagramm?

Comment: also .i just want to understand.Example: want to find prob that in this experiment i get divisible 3 number.So than 0.5*0.25+0.5*(1/3).?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would write the elements of $\Omega$ as pairs:
one side of the coin, followed by the result of the rolling whichever polyhedron you roll next.

For example, one element is $(H, 3).$ If you like you can write it $(H, t_3)$ to remind you that the second part of the pair is a side of a tetrahedron.

There are $10$ elements of $\Omega$ but I think it is not reasonable to assign equal probability to each one unless it is your intention to model a coin that is unfair and lands heads $60\%$ of the time.
You can partition $\Omega$ into the subsets with $H$ and the subsets with $T$;
if the coin is fair the two subsets should have equal probability measure and you can proceed from there.